# Transform simple mysql query to laravel 5.1 query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, query-builder

Please any one may help me to make this query in laravel5.1:

```
SELECT sum(orders.price) - (select sum(orders.price) 
    FROM orders INNER JOIN articles ON articles.id = orders.article_id 
    WHERE articles.forSale = false)
FROM orders INNER JOIN articles ON articles.id = orders.article_id 
     e articles.forSale=true
```

Comment: Thanks @manix for editing it :)

Comment: Please see updates

Comment: your answer is just using Query Builder, not eloquent. You should update the question to remove references to Eloquent if you don't need that in the solution.

Comment: @SlateEntropy thanks for note, it's done

Answer (score 1):

I got it :

```
    $query = "select (sum(orders.price) - 
                      (select sum(orders.price) from orders 
                        inner join articles on articles.id = orders.article_id                            
                        where articles.forSale = false)
                      ) as p1 from orders 
                        inner join articles on articles.id = orders.article_id 
                        where articles.forSale = true";        
    return \DB::select($query);
```